# Dojo - retrieve plugin configuration in custom layout

Tags: javascript, plugins, dojo, navigator

is it possible to retrieve somehow the plugin configuration in custom layout initializtion? I tried to achieve that by calling my plugin service "GetPluginConfigurationService", but it seems that calling any service is not possible before user login. Var config is undefined after service call:

```
return declare('myPlugin.Layout', [NavigatorMainLayout], {

    browseFeatureId: 'MyBrowseFeature',

    setFeatures: function(selectedFeatures, defaultFeature, defaultSecondaryPlugin) {
    var browseIndex = array.findIndex(selectedFeatures, function (feature) {
        return feature.id === this.browseFeatureId;
    }, this);

    var original = this.getInherited(arguments);
    var args = arguments;

    var repositoryId = "REPOSITORYID";

    var config = ecm.model.Request.invokePluginServiceSynchronous("MyPlugin", "GetPluginConfigurationService", { requestParams: {} });

    ....
},
```

Comment: I'm writing custom plugin for IBM navigator.